# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un programa en módulos con diferentes valores de entrada al mismo tiempo?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, hilos

He creado un programa en Python 3.6.12 en módulos que resuelve un problema complejo por lo que se demora casi 2 minutos, necesito ejecutar el mismo programa con diferentes valores de entrada y almacenar sus respectivas salidas. Lo cual me toma 2min por #veces llamado

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que tu programa acepte argumentos para indicar los valores de entrada. Puedes usar [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) para esto.

Por ejemplo, para añadir dos argumentos `--numero` y `--texto`, sería algo así:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Descripcion del programa.')
parser.add_argument('-n', '--numero', type=int, help='Numero a pasar al programa')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--texto', type=str, help='El texto a pasar al programa')

argumentos = parser.parse_args()

print('Numero: {}, texto: {}'.format(argumentos.numero, argumentos.texto))
```

Y así puedes ejecutar tu programa con `python programa.py -n 4 -t "Hola mundo"`.

Ahora lo que tienes que hacer es ejecutar tu programa el número de veces que quieras, enviando los argumentos de entrada que desees. Para esto puedes usar [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) Para ello, puedes crear otro archivo Python, con código similar a este:

```py
import subprocess

entradas = [
  { 'numero': 1, 'texto': 'Hola mundo' },
  { 'numero': 2, 'texto': 'foo bar' },
  { 'numero': 3, 'texto': 'Lorem ipsum' }
]

for entrada in entradas:
  try:
    comando = 'python programa.py -n {} -t "{}"'.format(entrada['numero'], entrada['texto'])
    subprocess.call(comando, shell=True)
  except OSError as e:
    print('Fallo la ejecucion:', e)
```

Luego podrás llamar a este programa, que se encargará de llamar cada vez con valores distintos a tu programa principal.